# GREP not detecting added elements in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array initialy loaded from the backend with 100 elements.

`console.log(array)` shows 100 elements.

Then I get 1 new element via ajax and add it to the array with `array.push(new_element);`

`console.log(array)` shows 101 elements.

If I `console.log(array[array.length-1])` I get the element I added.

Everything fine so far and data is correct. This is a capture from the added element.

[image]

---

Then I want to show a subset of the selected elements in a list.

```
sub_array = jQuery.grep(array, function(n) { return ( n.selected === 'True' });
```

The added 101 element is "selected", confirmed, but I don't get in the sub_array.

---

I checked all the logic and it's ok. Can't understand why I don't get the 101 element.

It seems like if the grep command get's the array data from the original version and not the updated one.

Like if it goes to a deeper level of memory or something like that. Is that possible?

**Some code**

```
// Part 1 - The original data comes from Django backend

$(document).ready(function(){
    window.array = {{ course_list|safe }};
};


// Part 2 - Adding extra value

$.ajax({
    url:'/myurl',
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',

    success:function(data){

        console.log(array);
        // Here I get the correct number of 100 elements

        new_course = JSON.parse(data.extra_course);
        array.push(new_course);

        console.log(array);
        // Here I get the correct number of 101 elements
    },

    error:function(data){
    },
});

// Part 3 - 

function create_agenda() {
    console.log(array[array.length-1]);
    // Here I get the added element correctly

    sub_array = jQuery.grep(array, function(n) { return ( n.selected === 'True') });
    // Here I don't get the element. Even filtering by other fields
};
```

**sub_array item example**

[image]

Any clue welcome!! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can show us some of the code? Maybe there is a typo somewhere. Are you sure n.selected is a a string 'True' and not a boolean `true`

Comment: There is no typo because the filter works fine with the initial data load from the backend. And confirmed selected is a string. I'll add the example.

Comment: If it's via Ajax you're likely not taking the **A** into account, but you post no code, so who knows. The console can be misleading as it shows an asynchronously-updated view of references.

Comment: From your question everything looks ok, but there is probably something wrong in your actual code which we cannot see.

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket.

Comment: @DaveNewton when I do the 'console.log(array)' and get 101 elements, I already have the ajax answer. And when I do 'console.log(array[array.length-1])' I can see the element. It is loaded. I'll add some code now

Comment: @JayB Updated the post with the bracket. In my original code it was ok.

Comment: what if you use the native `filter` method, just to check if you have the same problem:  `sub_array = array.filter(item => item.selected === 'True');` Let me know if there is any difference

Comment: @V.Sambor Same behaviour.

Comment: Interesting, then the problem is not related to `jQuery.grep` but rather to your array. Could you please show more code with the initialization of the array, where it is declared?

Comment: @V.Sambor just updated the code

Comment: @FranciscoGhelfi Could you please show one item of `sub_array` after the grep is done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208818/discussion-between-v-sambor-and-francisco-ghelfi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `ajax` repsonse the `data.extra_course` comes as an array not an object. 
You will have to get the first element of `extra_course` and push it to the `array` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/myurl',
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json',

  success: function (data) {

    console.log(array);
    // Here I get the correct number of 100 elements

    new_course = JSON.parse(data.extra_course);  // THIS RETURNS AN ARRAY

    array.push(new_course[0]);  // < ------------- USE THE FIRST OBJECT HERE

    console.log(array);
    // Here I get the correct number of 101 elements
  },

  error: function (data) {
  },
});
```

Comment: Happy to help! :)